# Anylogic. Agent search for other agents while moving

Tags: anylogic

In Anylogic, how to make an agent run an action (like search in a certain radius for an agent) while moving towards another agent? I'm using PML to move to another agent but how can I include an intermediate task in the flow? Maybe combining with state charts? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say with these details but I feel like you may want something of this sort:

This event should be inside the agent that is moving (in which case the "yourAgent." should be removed:

[image: Conditional Event]

Another option is to have a statechart inside the agent that is moving, something like this:
You trigger the message transition when your agent starts moving and you create a conditional transition with the condition distanceTo(otherAgent)[image: statechart]

There are more ways of doing this... but these 2 came to mind first

Comment: Thanks! the first one looks neat!, I'll try it...gracias!